# Azure Event hubs changing the minimum of the reciever

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I'm using the EventProcessorHost to get messages off an event hub. Is there an easy way to change the maximum number of messages that are pulled off at a time. Right now the default is 10 and I know when using a normal EventReciever it is relatively easy to change the default, but I couldn't find any documentation for when using EventProcessor.

I want so when ProcessEventsAsync is called the maximum number of messages passed in to be less than 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by providing EventProcessorOptions when registering EventProcessor with MaxBatchSize property modified (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.eventprocessoroptions.maxbatchsize.aspx). 
For example:

```
 var eventProcessorHost = new EventProcessorHost(...);

 await eventProcessorHost.RegisterEventProcessorAsync<MyEventProcessor>(new EventProcessorOptions{MaxBatchSize = 5});
```